# Domain Not Secured with Valet 3 (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-valet

I have noticed that in both Chrome and Firefox, my valet secured site has been displayed as Not Secure. It somehow works fine in Safari.  Has anyone recently experienced this?

When I do `valet secured`, I can see my site is (supposed to be) secured as attached.

[image]

Suspect it might have something to do with my recent updates.

Currently on Composer 2 / Laravel 9 / PHP 8.0 / Value 3

Have tried reinstalling valet, restarting valet, link/unlink, and secure/unsecure with no luck.

Comment: Are you accessing `https`? Did you click on `Not Secured` and see why it is saying that?

Comment: @matiaslauriti it shows the newly created certificate. And yes accessing `https`

Comment: And what is the error? Usually it will say if the certificate has expired, was certified from an untrusted entity and similar stuff, what is it showing? Could you share a screenshot?

Comment: Yes please see here - https://ibb.co/542gPMc
Also - https://ibb.co/3mBmRWp
Thank you!

Comment: What does it shows or goes to if you click on `Certificate is not valid` on the second screenshot?

Comment: @matiaslauriti it shows the first screen: https://ibb.co/542gPMc

Comment: I am not sure then, I think it is related to the Firefox and Chrome version. Maybe they are not accepting the Issuer as valid due to security concerns. I would ask in [sf] or [su]

Comment: @matiaslauriti thanks a lot for trying to help. I have no idea what happened so I went to bed with frustration. And this morning after I rebooted the laptop, everything works again. Maybe it was the cache or something? But I'm glad it's functioning again. Just in case i'd be useful for anyone - I did `rm ~/.config/valet/CA/*` and `valet install` to replaced the outdated certificate authority (CA).

Comment: `rm ~/.config/valet/CA/*` and `valet install` did the trick for me - thank you @AndreW. !
This was the correct answer for me. Chrome complained, in Firefox it worked fine.
Those did not work for me: reboot, uninstall nginx + valet install, unsecure/secure either linked or parked.
At some point I deleted the CA in macos key access but it does not get added back with valet install. Deleting the folder was the missing piece for me.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Doing the following will solve the issue:

1. `rm ~/.config/valet/CA/*`
2. `valet install`

The first command replaces the outdated certificate authority (CA). The second does the trick to put back the missing files.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the issue for me. My issue started after I upgraded Chrome to the latest version. Removing the CA folder and reinstalling valet certificates fixed it for me.

Comment: @TamikSoziev I'm glad it did!

Comment: Thank you! This fixed error for me as well :)

Comment: @WillKim glad that it did! :)

Comment: This randomly started happening to me today, upgraded Valet, did `valet install` and `valet unsecure` then `valet secure` and nothing worked without your fix to delete the CA contents, thank you!!!

Comment: damn this should be in the documentation. Yup, that worked for me as well.

Comment: After `valet install` I did have to manually run `valet secure` for each site. Overall fixed my issue though. Thank you.